# List only child categories within posts

Tags: categories

I am using the_category() to display categories in my posts that are also filed in child-categories. Unfortunately this also displays the parent category which i would love to hide. Is there a way to only display the child categories and not the parent category?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post `the_category()` code you use?

Comment: At the moment I am using this `<?php the_category('/ '); ?>` to display the categories within the post. But as I said it's also displaying the parent categories and I would like to display the child categories only.

Comment: A potentially simpler solution would be to not select the parent category when you save the post. A parent category archive will include posts belonging to its children categories.

Comment: @LianaMir: Thank you this helped. I thought it was going to cause problems with my custom loops, but all is fine. Thanks!